# ASP.NET Core - Working with data from HTTP Post Request

Tags: http-post, asp.net-core-webapi, http-get

i'm learning ASP.NET Core right now and got a little stuck with a ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API. I have to handle Json Data sent as an Http Post by a third party application.
It sends only one Json Attribute called eMail.

```
{
 "eMail":"test@xyz.com"
}
```

I have to use the E-Mail address to lookup a Table in my Database and respond with the Customer Name also in Json.

**Three Questions:**
How can i capture this Post Request and convert the E-Mail Address into a string, so I can use it in an SQL Query?
How do i respond the result (Customer Name) as Json?
Is this even possible? Because i might be completly wrong with my thinking here.

I'd be really glad for a simple explanation or even an example. Reading material is also very welcome, as i am new to all of this but I want to keep learning. Apologies if my questions and thinking here is plain stupid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a demo worked:
Model:

```
public class User { 
        public string eMail { get; set; }
    }
```

Action:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("TestJson")]
        public object TestJson([FromBody]User o) {
            return new { CustomerName = o.eMail };
        }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. This helped alot. I kind of got lost in the GET/POST/PUT Reading Material.